# Play an animation when touch moved is certain distance from touch began

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, touch, unityscript

i am new to unityscript and unity and i am trying to make an animation trigger when the touch moved position is +100 to the right of touch began, so i have also tried +500 and +1000 and it seems that the animation is playing when the touch is past 100,500,or 1000 on the screen, not the touch.began position + (the amount), any help is appreciated, thank you for your time as i am new to unityscript

```
#pragma strict
var distance : float = 10;
var joystick : GameObject;
private var first : boolean = false;
function Start () {

}

function Update () {
transform.eulerAngles = Vector3(0,Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y + 180,0);

var v3Pos : Vector3;
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && 
          Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

            // Get movement of the finger since last frame
            var touchDeltaPosition:Vector2 = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            if(!first){
            var touchdet : Vector2 = touchDeltaPosition;
            first = true;
            }

            // Move object across XY plane
            v3Pos = Vector3(touchDeltaPosition.x, touchDeltaPosition.y, distance);
         transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(v3Pos);
        }


 if (Input.touchCount > 0 && 
          Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {

            // Get movement of the finger since last frame
            var touchAlphaPosition:Vector2 = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

            // Move object across XY plane
            v3Pos = Vector3(touchAlphaPosition.x, touchAlphaPosition.y, distance);
         transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(v3Pos);
        }

        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && 
          (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended || Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Canceled )) {

            // Get movement of the finger since last frame
            var touchBetaPosition:Vector2 = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            first = false;
            // Move object across XY plane
            v3Pos = Vector3(touchBetaPosition.x, 600, distance);
         transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(v3Pos);
        }

        if(first)
        {
        if(touchAlphaPosition.x > touchdet.x + 100)
        {
        animation.Play("Right");
        }
        }

}
```

Comment: This seems more of a "what is wrong with my code" question than a "how do I do this" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable touchDet is declared and initialized in the function Update, so the value is not persisted between function calls. touchDet in all but the iteration where TouchPhase.Began event fires will always be equal to Vector2.zero.

Comment: thanks man, you were right, im new to javascript,so, i can only get better, thanks again